# Consume REST service from Xamarin

Tags: rest, xamarin

I'm trying to consume REST services in my Xamarin app from my WEB API server (ASP.NET) and I always get the following error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 400 (Bad Request)
at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode
```

It used to work and don't know why it stopped.

```
var content = await Client.GetStringAsync("http://10.0.0.1:55592/odata/Sections/");
```

10.0.0.1:55592 is the WEB API server (same address as the Xamarin client).
doing REST queries from the browser work good, so I guess it's something related to the Android\Xamarin...

in addition, doing REST query from the Xamarin to https://api.trackseries.tv/v1/Stats/TopSeries works as well...

So I think it's something that is not configured well.
CORS is enabled in my Web API server as well.

Comment: You put `http://10.0.0.1:55592/odata/Sections/` on browser and succeed?

Comment: no. not working
I also get 400 error, but http://10.0.0.1:55592/odata/Sections/ works

Comment: I don't understand... it works or not on browser? The url you say it works it's the same I pasted on my comment but you started saying "no. not working"

Comment: so adding the trailing "/" breaks it?

Comment: sorry wrong paste
http://localhost:55592/odata/Sections/ works

Comment: So you have a web server running on a Mac/PC and you can access it from a browser on the same Mac/PC, but not from an Android device. What about if you use a browser on the device?

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Authentication.user + ":" + Authentication.pass));
var basicAuth = string.Format("{0}", credentials);
request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", basicAuth);
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
return response;
```

Comment: Please add some description about your answer